# traceback in global sequence alignment

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics

I am facing problem of tracing back the global sequence alignment. My first sequence is ATTGCGCGCAT and second sequence is ATGCTTAACCA. The traceback result should be
A T T G C _ _ _ G C G C A T
A _ T G C T T A A C _ C A _
But the code i am using unable to output that result.

I had tried to browse the google for reference but there are few reference of traceback written in Java.

```
private static void traceback(String seqOne, String seqTwo,int[][]matrix) {


    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(), s2 = new StringBuilder();

    for ( int i = seqOne.length(),  j = seqTwo.length(); i > 0 && j > 0; ) {
        if (i > 0 && j > 0 && (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i - 1][j - 1]) ) {
            s1.append(seqOne.charAt(--i));
            s2.append(seqTwo.charAt(--j));
        } else if ( i > 0 && (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i - 1][j] + 1) ) {
            s1.append(seqOne.charAt(--i));
            s2.append("-");
        } else if ( j > 0 && (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j - 1] + 1) ) {
            s2.append(seqTwo.charAt(--j));
            s1.append("-");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(s1.reverse().toString());
    System.out.println(s2.reverse().toString());

}
```

Comment: What do you get as output?

Comment: ATTGCGCGCAT--
--C--TTAA-CCA

Comment: Could you define "traceback?"

Comment: I believe he wants to implement [this](http://avatar.se/lectures/molbioinfo2001/dynprog/dynamic.html)

Comment: @michalk yes i wan to implement that

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer i used the online stimulator to demo

[image: traceback]

Comment: Great but he wants to solve any traceback using code and not online tool...

Comment: im showing the example to @benjamin to explain the traceback

Comment: but i couldn't post an image in the comment section

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I did not notice that you are the person who asked the question. In this case instead of providing such information in answer, you can [edit] your question.